# Вопрос про связи между сущностями в базе данных

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, sql-server

Попалась такая ситуация: Есть две таблицы "Операция_сравнения" и "Логическая_операция". В таблице Логическая_операция подразумевал сделать два внешних ключа на таблицу Операция_сравнения. То есть любая логическая операция связана сразу с двумя операциями сравнения. Можно ли так вообще делать? Как это будет выглядеть, то есть на ER-схеме? Это будет связь многие ко многим или как?

Например мне нужно сохранить в базу данных правило: "**Если значение x1 >= 50 AND значение x2 < 1000 то ...**". Пример как это я себе представляю в виде таблиц:
[image: Таблицы]

Comment: Покажите схематично( а лучше таблично), что именно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @SwaD добавил изменения.

Comment: Связь будет 1 ко многим. 1, это операция сравнения, много это логическая операция. Будет 2 связи: сравнение.id -> логичкаяПоле1 и такая же на поле 2

Comment: @SwaD то есть на ER-схеме нужно рисовать две связи?